# Taking user to other page without changing the js file

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm trying to prompt the user for the players names in an html page linked to a JS file, I need to re-use the names later in the game, but I don't think I can store them in local storage, so I was wondering is there any other way I can show the user another page without redirecting them to another one ?

You're welcome to suggest other solutions.

Comment: You mean you need to navigating between pages without loading JS files every time, Only once when the site opens?

Comment: @mohammedalshobaki I rather need to manipulate two html pages with one js file, which I can't do, so I'm looking for another way to do it.

Comment: Can you try AJAX to update the content and remain footer and header when navigating between pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hidden `<div>` with a form to enter the names.

Minimal Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="display: none" class="overlay" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Player Name">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Confirm">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.overlay
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**JS:**

To show the prompt:

```
document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
```

To hide the prompt:

```
document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: I'm dynamically creating the names inputs depending on the number of players :

Comment: const x = localStorage.getItem('playersNum');
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  const newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
  newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");

  parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);
}

Comment: I rather need to hide this one and show another one for the game.

Comment: Why not put both the game and the name prompt in an overlay like in my answer and show/hide them when needed?